# Alterando o botão de voltar

Tags: android

Estou querendo alterar esse botao de voltar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui no fórum eu encontrei esse código

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item> <!-- Icone de voltar -->
```

Mas ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O icone tomou toda a toolbar e escondeu o titulo.

Pela lógica do código, essa imagem que está no drawable iria aparecer em todas as telas com está função. Tem como determinar um tamanho por código nesta imagem? (Fiz a imagem da seta em tamanho reduzido, mas perdeu a qualidade) É possível colocar uma drawable para cada tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocando o item `android:homeAsUpIndicator`
no tema padrão do aplicativo fará com que todas as activities que usem esse tema (possivelmente "AppTheme") usem-o.

> "Tem como determinar um tamanho por código nesta imagem?"

O guia de design do Android tem métricas definidas [nesse aspecto](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons), não acho que seja possível.
[Mais referências](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar).

> "Fiz a imagem da seta em tamanho reduzido, mas perdeu a qualidade"

Recomendo usar o [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/), uma ótima ferramenta online que pode gerar as imagens nas dimensões corretas.

> "É possível colocar uma drawable para cada tela?"

Sim, ao invés de definir o drawable no tema, use o método [setHomeAsUpIndicator()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeAsUpIndicator(int)) em cada activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icone_toolbar); // <--
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Fico grato pela ajuda!